# sql join 'on' operator not filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

This may be a duplicate but I don't know how to search correctly. I can write basic sql, and know concept 'Cartesian product'. But I'm always to some degree confused about the **on** in join. Example in sqlserver:

```
A | B
--+--
1 | 2
2 | 3

select * from ta left join tb on  ta.A = 2     --??!

A | B
--+--
1 | Null
2 | 2
2 | 3

select * from ta left join tb on  tb.B = 2    --seems easier to understand

A | B
--+--
1 | 2
2 | 2
```

Could any one explain the 1st sql(**on  ta.A = 2**), why are column A not filtered. By the way I know the most common use of on ta.ColA=tb.ColB, but in this question I just want to know how **on** works.

Comment: You have an error in your output which makes it harder to understand the problem. In your first output, the second row should have `A=2`, not `A=1`.

Comment: Sorry, I updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `LEFT JOIN` always follow the following rules:

1. Take all rows from the left side of the join
2. Find any matching rows from the right side of the join, using the `ON ...` clause to find those rows.
3. Depending on the number of rows found from the right side, do the following:

   - No rows: produce a single row from the left side in the results and make all columns that would've come from the right side `NULL`
   - One row: Combine the single row from the left side with the single row from the right side
   - Multiple rows: Combine the single row from the left side with each of the rows from the right side, producing multiple rows in the output

So your `ON TA.A=2` is only used to filter rows from the right side.

Now, you have an error in your question which makes it harder to just read what the problem is.

This output:

```
A | B
--+--
1 | Null
1 | 2             <-- notice A=1 here, this is incorrect
2 | 3
```

should be this:

```
A | B
--+--
1 | Null
2 | 2             <-- notice A=2 here
2 | 3
```

Basically, your query does this:

- Take all rows from `TA`
- Find rows from `TB` where `TA.A=2` is true, this will only happen when you're at the `A=2` row, which is why you have `Null` for `A=1`.
- Since you don't specify which of the `TB` rows you want, all of those rows will be combined with the single row where `A=2`.

Comment: Is it really worth separating "one row" and "multiple rows" into separate cases?

Comment: From experience having to explain this to others, I'd say yes.

Answer (score 3):

In a `LEFT JOIN`, all rows from the left side of the join will *always* be preserved. The `ON` condition determines whether any rows from the right side will be successfully joined to these rows.

So,

```
select * from ta left join tb on  ta.A = 2     --??!

A | B
--+--
1 | Null
2 | 2
2 | 3
```

When `A` is equal to `1`, the condition `ta.A = 2` is never true, and so *no* rows from `tb` are preserved.

When `A` is equal to `2`, the condition `ta.A = 2` is true, and so *all* rows from `tb` are joined to such rows in `ta`.

Comment: Accept the other since he not only answered, but also corrected my error in original output. However, you are faster!